# How to pass values from other table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I would like to calculate the percentage of sales and returns for every product and product sub category.

```
WITH F1 (PROD_CAT, PROD_SUB_CAT, TOTAL_SALES) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PRODUCT_CAT_CODE,
        PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE,
        SUM(TOTAL_AMT)
    FROM
        TRANSACTION_INFO
    WHERE 
        TOTAL_AMT > 0
    GROUP BY 
        PRODUCT_CAT_CODE, PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE
), F2 (PROD_CAT, PROD_SUB_CAT, TOTAL_RETURNS) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PRODUCT_CAT_CODE,
        PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE,
        SUM(TOTAL_AMT)
    FROM
        TRANSACTION_INFO
    WHERE 
        TOTAL_AMT < 0
    GROUP BY 
        PRODUCT_CAT_CODE, PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE
)
SELECT 
    T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE,
    T1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE,
    F1.TOTAL_SALES,
    F1.TOTAL_SALES * 100 / (SELECT SUM(TOTAL_AMT)
                            FROM TRANSACTION_INFO) AS [%AGE TOTAL SALES],
    F2.TOTAL_RETURNS, 
    F2.TOTAL_RETURNS * 100 / (SELECT SUM(TOTAL_AMT)
                              FROM TRANSACTION_INFO) AS [%AGE TOTAL_RETURNS]
FROM 
    TRANSACTION_INFO T1
INNER JOIN 
    F1 ON T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F1.PROD_CAT
INNER JOIN 
    F2 ON T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F2.PROD_CAT
WHERE 
    T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F1.PROD_CAT
    AND T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F2.PROD_CAT
GROUP BY 
    T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE,
    T1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE,
    F1.TOTAL_SALES,
    F2.TOTAL_RETURNS
```

This returns 467 records, where I have just 23 records of products.

Please suggest any way to handle this...

Comment: Instead of joining same table several times to collect the total, you could use something like `SUM(case when TOTAL_AMT > 0 then TOTAL_AMT else 0 end), SUM(case when TOTAL_AMT < 0 then TOTAL_AMT else 0 end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think while joining the Transaction_info you should also consider product_sub_cat like below:

```
FROM TRANSACTION_INFO T1
INNER JOIN F1 ON T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F1.PROD_CAT AND T1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE = F1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE
INNER JOIN F2 ON T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F2.PROD_CAT AND T2.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE = F1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE
```

& there seems no use of the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on *both* `PRODUCT_CAT_CODE` *and* `PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE`.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM TRANSACTION_INFO T1
INNER JOIN F1 ON T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F1.PROD_CAT
    AND T1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE = F1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE
INNER JOIN F2 ON T1.PRODUCT_CAT_CODE = F2.PROD_CAT
    AND T1.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE = F2.PRODUCT_SUBCAT_CODE
WHERE ...
```